Prevent Firebase SDK Auto-config attempt
I'm building a react website which allows users to authenticate via SSO using Google Identity Platform, Firebase and OIDC. I'm using the firebase javascript sdk v10.6.0, and I've noticed that when I call the signInWithRedirect method, the SDK makes a fetch call to this endpoint:
https://my-project-id.firebaseapp.com/__/firebase/init.json
I've found this SO question which mentions that this is an auto-configuration feature. Here is my initialization and sign-in function:
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth, signInWithRedirect } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(
  {
    apiKey: process.env.FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID
  },
  'auth-app'
);

const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);


const signIn = (email, providerId) => {

  const provider = new OAuthProvider(providerId);

  const redirectParams = getRedirectParams();

  provider.setCustomParameters({
    login_hint: email,
    ...redirectParams,
  });

  signInWithRedirect(firebaseAuth, provider);
}

I am not using Firebase hosting, and I am not fetching the init.json file, or the init.js file at any point in my own code, as is mentioned in this somewhat-related documentation
Is there any way to disable this fetch call? I don't want to auto-configure, and it takes 500-1000ms for this fetch to return, slowing down the authentication flow.

Are you asking the right question?  Since you didn't show any code, we don't know if you are initializing the Firebase SDK in such a way that requires this fetch, or if you're initializing it yourself.  Please edit the question to show the code that doesn't work the way you expect. We should be able to reproduce the unexpected behavior using the code and instructions you provide.

@DougStevenson I've added the requested code. Aslo, your comment implies that whether or not the fetch happens depends on how the SDK is initialized. Is that the case? I can't find any documentation on this auto-configure feature.

Please edit the question to show how you are importing the SDK and deploying your code.  The automatic init is part of how Firebase Hosting works, and is documented here.  If you think that the behavior of the SDK is wrong and it should not fetch anything for your case, then file an issue on GitHub for that.

@DougStevenson While there is a section in the documentation you linked titled "SDK auto-configuration", reading that section reveals that you can choose to "auto-configure" by either including a JS file, or fetching/parsing a JSON file that FB hosting makes available. Neither of these behaviors matches my case, although they are related.
